CW-pair attaching maps
Let $X,B,A$ be CW-complexes where $A$ is a subcomplex of $B$ which is a subcomplex of $X$. This implies that $A$ is a subcomplex of $X$. How are the attaching maps in $(X,A)$, induced from those of $(X,B)$ and $(B,A)$, defined?
$(X,B)$ has attaching maps $f_n: \bigvee \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \longrightarrow X^{n-1} \cup B$ and $(B,A)$ has attaching maps $g_n: \bigvee \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \longrightarrow B^{n-1} \cup A$. Then $(X,A)$ has attaching maps $h_n: \bigvee \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \longrightarrow X^{n-1} \cup A$ but how does this take into account the CW-complex $B$?

I think you misunderstood something.
There are no attaching maps for a pair $(Y,C)$, where $Y$ is a CW-complex and $C$ is a subcomplex. There is an attaching map $\phi^n_i : S^{n-1} \to Y^{n-1}$ for each $n$-cell $e^n_i$ of $Y$; the subcomplex $C$ does not play any role here.
However, $C$ inherits attaching maps from $Y$. Each $n$-cell $e^n_i$ of $C$ is an $n$-cell of $Y$ with attaching map $\phi^n_i : S^{n-1} \to Y^{n-1}$. Since $C$ is subcomplex, $\phi^n_i(S^{n-1}) \subset C^{n-1} \subset Y^{n-1}$, thus we may regard $\phi^n_i$ as a map  $\phi^n_i : S^{n-1} \to C^{n-1}$.
There is, however, the concept of a relative CW-complex $(Z,D)$. Here $Z$ is given space (not necessarily a CW-complex) which is understood as the "$(-1)$-skeleton" of $Z$. Then $Z^0$ is obtained from $Z^{-1}$ by taking the disjoint union with a discrete set, then attaching $1$-cells to $Z^0$, etc.  See also topology of relative CW complex.
Anyway, this is not related to your question.

So a relative CW-complex has attaching maps. Doesn't this mean a CW-pair has attaching maps as a CW-pair is a relative CW-complex?

@Troy You can indeed regard each CW-pair $(Y,C)$ as  a relative CW-complex. But in this case the attaching maps of $Y$ have nothing to do with $C$. First $Y$ is built by taking a discrete $Y^0$ and then successively attaching $1$-cells, $2$-cells. etc. Subcomplexes $C$ can only be formed after we have constructed $Y$. Then $C$ receives attaching maps inherited from $Y$. In a general relative CW-complex $(Z,D)$ the space $D$ is a given part needed for the construction of $Z$. The attaching maps of $Z$ are related to $D$ because $D \subset Z^{n-1}$ for all $n$.

If we can regard the CW-pair $(Y,C)$ as a relative CW-complex then can't we say that $Y$ is constructed from $C$ and then the attaching maps of $Y$ are related to $C$.

@Troy As I wrote, we can regard $(Y,C)$ as a relative CW-complex. But if we start with a CW-complex $C$ and want to construct a CW-complex $Y$ containing $C$ as a subcomplex, we have to very careful with the attaching maps. The standard construction of a relative CW-complex $(\tilde Y, C)$ based on $C$ allows to attach $n$-cells via arbitrary maps $S^{n-1} \to \tilde Y^{n-1}$, where each $\tilde Y^{n-1}$ contains $C$. Doing so, the CW-structure of $C$ does not play a role here and $C$ will in general be no subcomplex of $\tilde Y$, but only a subspace.

Being careful means that the  attaching maps of $n$-cells must have images not containing points in $C \setminus C^{n-1}$. However, this is not a natural approach. Actually we first construct $Y$ and then determine subcomplexes of $Y$.

Thankyou. This may be a different question, but given a CW-complex $X$ with attaching maps $f_{n+1} : \mathbb{S}^n \longrightarrow X^n$ and $f_n : \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \longrightarrow X^{n-1}$, is the restriction of $f_{n+1}$ to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ equal to the attaching map $f_n$?

@Troy No, the attaching maps in different dimensions are completely independent in general. If you have an attaching map $f_{n+1} : S^n \to X^n$, then you may coincidentally have $f_{n+1}(S^{n-1}) \subset X^{n-1}$ and the restriction may coincidentally agree with some attaching map of an $n$-cell.

So if the attaching maps $f_{n+1} : \mathbb{S}^n \longrightarrow X^n$ are independent, can we use the one 0-cell and one n-cell structure on $\mathbb{S}^n$ for $n \geq 1$?

@Troy Yes, correct!
